# new question stats

Tags: discussion, site-statistics

Is there a way to see stats for new questions on the site, other than the sidebar item that says how many questions there are?  It would be cool if there were a place to see stats for the site, including new questions per day, and links to those questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review

or

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction

or

http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

?

Comment: Yes, all 3 combined really help with what i need.